# HttpSession creates session for one Java servlet but doesn't share it in another servlet using getSession()

Tags: java, session, servlets, httpsession

I have a Java servlet passing attributes to the session using `HttpSession`. The `getSession()` method, as far as I know, is allowing me to pass objects to the session using `setAttribute(String name, Object value)` . I say as far as I know because this servlet is the only one currently able to get the session. The other servlet I want to get the attributes using `getAttribute(String name)` . However, when I initialize an HttpSession variable, it doesn't work.

Here is the relevant section of code in the `doPost()` method of the first servlet `NewTextLog` :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
System.out.println("NewTextLog: " + session.getId() );
session.setAttribute("textlog", textlog);
session.setAttribute("param", param);
```

Don't worry about the objects. I can confirm there are objects to provide to the attributes but if the session can't be shared it doesn't matter anyway. I can confirm that the `session` does initialize successfully when I run my application because the sysout does print what I expected it to. A sample output from one time I ran it would be `NewTextLog: 4657DAFB8F5580397CB228AEF618D6DB` . Now, here are the relevant lines in the `doGet()` method of my second servlet, `LogData` :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
System.out.println(session);
System.out.println("LogData: " + session.getId() );
TextLog textlog = (TextLog) session.getAttribute("textlog");    
String param = (String) session.getAttribute("param");
```

I think the problem must be somewhere on this side of things because neither of those sysouts print anything at all. If `session` were null, that should have at least been printed. Nothing. It's bizarre too because I was able to get it working for a short while. I did make some minor tweaks to the code but I think I commented all the changes out and even if I didn't, I really don't think I changed anything relevant to the functioning of these lines. It's as though the thing just decided to quit on me.

I'm wondering if there's anything required to target the second servlet to make sure it can get a hold of the session. However, I though the point of using the session was so that any servlet could access it regardless of targeting. Sorry if this is a beginner's question. In any case, if anyone is wondering, I used annotations instead of web.xml for servlet mapping. Maybe this makes a difference. For `NewTextLog` my annotation is `@WebServlet("/logs")` and for `LogData`, it's `@WebServlet("/logdata")` .

There's a lot of stuff about HttpSession on here, and I did try other methods but they don't seem to work. The long and short of it is that it once worked, and now it doesn't. Can anyone please tell me if they have experience with similar problems or if the issue is readily apparent?

Update:
Using the Eclipse debugger, I started stepping through the code, with Step Return so it wouldn't take me forever to step through all the classes invoked with the `doGet()` call. There's a class in Tomcat that I can't step through called `ThreadPoolExecutor` .  Absolute path is `C:\Users\tylab\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util-9.0.68-sources.jar\org\apache\tomcat\util\threads\ThreadPoolExecutor` . I literally have grey buttons where my Step Into, Step Over and Step Return buttons are, which cannot be pressed. I will put the method it's stuck at here and comment on exactly what line it stops at:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")  // task cannot be null
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
   Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
   Runnable task = w.firstTask;
   w.firstTask = null;
   w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
   boolean completedAbruptly = true;
   try {
       while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
           w.lock();
           // If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
           // if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
           // requires a recheck in second case to deal with
           // shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
           if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
                (Thread.interrupted() &&
                 runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
                 !wt.isInterrupted()) {
                 wt.interrupt();
           }
           try {
               beforeExecute(wt, task);
               try {
                   task.run();
                   afterExecute(task, null);      //Line 1192: this is where it stops
               } catch (Throwable ex) {
                   afterExecute(task, ex);
                   throw ex;
               }
           } finally {
               task = null;
               w.completedTasks++;
               w.unlock();
           }
       }
       completedAbruptly = false;
   } finally {
       processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
   }
}
```

I have absolutely no experience digging into the ditches of all these extremely large classes that run the Tomcat server, so I really have no idea what this all means. I'm hoping someone else might be able to figure out what is going on. Is the execution of my `doGet()` stopping at this point when I run my program normally? I feel like that would explain a lot.

Comment: Are you sure your second servlet is invoked? You should either get a null pointer exception or something written out on the console. Have you checked for errors? Have you placed a breakpoint for debugging?

Comment: @Bogdan I'm not sure. But after all the server startup operations and clicking through my pages, when this particular `doGet()` method is called, I only get these two lines:
`Dec. 01, 2022 11:43:00 A.M. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1315] milliseconds`

I haven't placed a breakpoint. I really should make this a habit I suppose.

Comment: @Bogdan I added some new information on the results of debugging in case you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: Wrap your code into a try catch and see if you can catch something. The problem is in your code, not the server code (so no need to debug that deep). Like I said, you should get some sort of indication of what's wrong in the logs. Maybe you are not logging to console?